# How to load data to table clearing loaded data before?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm making a mini-inventory control system. This is my database's invoice table. 
[image: INVOICE TABLE]

columns are inid(p), itid(p), cuid(p), itname, qty, sprice, total, isdate, redate

This is my Invoice interface when searching an old invoice using invoice id (inid). I already searched one before. Every data set to text fields and table properly. But the thing is when I'm searching another invoice other data will set properly but table not clear and second search's data also set under the first search's data to the given table.

[image: FIRST SEARCH]


this is second search interface. 
[image: SECOND SEARCH]
Given below is my source code of search.

```
JDBC db = new JDBC();
public boolean b;   

  public void selectFromDate(JComboBox combodate, JDateChooser isdate, JDateChooser redate,       DateSpinner retime, DateSpinner istime,
          JTable jtable1, JTextField txtCuid, JTextField txtCuName, JTextField txtCuAdd,
          JTextField txtCuTp, JTextField txtgtotal, JTextField txtAdvance, JTextField txtDue,
          JTextField txtInvoiceID, JTextField txtDamage, JTextField txtInvoiceTotal) {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        ResultSet rs1 = db.getData("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE isdate='" + combodate.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'");
        if (rs1.next()) {
            b = true;
            while (rs1.next()) {                    
                txtInvoiceID.setText((rs1.getString("inid")));
            Vector v = new Vector();
            DefaultTableModel dd = (DefaultTableModel) jtable1.getModel();
               dd.setRowCount(0);
            v.add(rs1.getInt("itid"));
            v.add(rs1.getString("itname"));
            v.add(rs1.getInt("qty"));
            v.add(rs1.getDouble("sprice"));
            v.add(rs1.getDouble("total"));
            dd.addRow(v);

            String maindate1 = rs1.getString("isdate");
            String date1 = maindate1.substring(0, 10);
            String time1 = maindate1.substring(11, 19);

            Date d1 = formatter1.parse(date1);
            Date t1 = formatter2.parse(time1);

            isdate.setDate(d1);
            istime.setValue(t1);

            String maindate2 = rs1.getString("redate");
            String date2 = maindate2.substring(0, 10);
            String time2 = maindate2.substring(11, 19);

            Date d = formatter1.parse(date2);
            Date t = formatter2.parse(time2);

            redate.setDate(d);
            retime.setValue(t);


            try {
                ResultSet rs2 = db.getData("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cuid='" + rs1.getInt("cuid") + "'");
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    txtCuid.setText(String.valueOf(rs1.getInt("cuid")));
                    txtCuName.setText(rs2.getString("cuname"));
                    txtCuAdd.setText(rs2.getString("cuadd"));
                    txtCuTp.setText(rs2.getString("cutp"));

                    try {
                        ResultSet rs3 = db.getData("SELECT * FROM indetails WHERE inid='" + rs1.getInt("inid") + "'");
                        if (rs3.first()) {
                            txtgtotal.setText(String.valueOf(rs3.getDouble("gtotal")));
                            txtAdvance.setText(String.valueOf(rs3.getDouble("advance")));
                            txtDue.setText(String.valueOf(rs3.getDouble("due")));
                            try {
                                ResultSet rs4 = db.getData("SELECT * FROM infinal WHERE inid=" + rs1.getInt("inid") + "");
                                if (rs4.first()) {
                                    txtDamage.setText(String.valueOf(rs4.getDouble("dcost")));
                                    txtInvoiceTotal.setText(String.valueOf(rs4.getDouble("intotal")));

                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invoice is not finalised");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs4" + e);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs3" + e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs2" + e);
            }
            }

        } else {
            b = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs1");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + "rs1 " + " " + e);
    }
}
}
```

When I comment dd.setRowCount(0); I only get same result.. Please help me.

My JDBC class code.

```
package Model;

import static Model.JDBC.con;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JDBC {

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cateringnew";
static Connection con;
//10.226.50.130

private void setCon() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}

private Connection getCon() throws Exception {
    if (con == null) {
        setCon();
        System.out.println("setCon");
    }
    System.out.println("getCon");
    return con;
}


  public void putData(String sql) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement state = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
        state.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("putDate");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}

public ResultSet getData(String sql) throws Exception {

    Statement state = getCon().createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = state.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println("getData");
    return rset;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please more clearly explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around it, but I only half understand what the program is supposed to do, and maybe half understand what your code is supposed to do (not from your explanation, but from just staring at your code)

Comment: true that.. from the description I thought that she is facing problems with the refresh of the table.

Comment: @peeskillet problem is every search in invoice load in the same table. As a example in inid = 1 combo box search if I got to 2rows to table, When I search inid=2 in combo box it's search's data also load in that table starting from row 3. I explained it using pictures.

Comment: @ADi answer in given up

Comment: The problem may be in the `JDBC` class...

Comment: @Madprogrammer I added JDBC class cord also in Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways you can clear a UI form, one of the simplest is to simply reset the models with empty/default instance.  This works well for `JTable`, `JTree`, `JList` and `JComboBox`.

Based on your example code, you could do something like...

```
DefaultTableModel dd = new DefaultTableModel();
// Set the columns for the table model...
jtable1.setModel(dd);
while (rs1.next()) {                    
    txtInvoiceID.setText((rs1.getString("inid")));
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add(rs1.getInt("itid"));
    v.add(rs1.getString("itname"));
    v.add(rs1.getInt("qty"));
    v.add(rs1.getDouble("sprice"));
    v.add(rs1.getDouble("total"));
    dd.addRow(v);
```

Or you could do something like...

```
DefaultTableModel dd = (DefaultTableModel) jtable1.getModel();
dd.setRowCount(0);
while (rs1.next()) {                    
    txtInvoiceID.setText((rs1.getString("inid")));
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add(rs1.getInt("itid"));
    v.add(rs1.getString("itname"));
    v.add(rs1.getInt("qty"));
    v.add(rs1.getDouble("sprice"));
    v.add(rs1.getDouble("total"));
    dd.addRow(v);
```

Which would be simpler, as you don't need to reconstruct the column inforamtion each time.

Comment: That certainly makes a change :P

Comment: It's a nice change to see a solution I suggest actually work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for removing all rows:

```
    int count = yourTable.getRowCount();

    for(int i = count-1;i>=0;i--){
        DefaultTableModel dft = (DefaultTableModel)yourTable.getModel();
        dft.removeRow(i);
    }
```

In my opinion, create a method as refresh, so that at each stage, the data will be refreshed calling that method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yeah, I didn't think about that.. I used to do this when I used swing.

Comment: wait sorry I was away.. wait I'm tring

Comment: @Madprogrammer Aru talking about this? DefaultTableModel df = new DefaultTableModel().jtable1.getmodle(); This is not working

Comment: @Dilini Actually, I was thinking more along the lines of of `jtable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel())`...

Comment: in here DefaultTableModel df = jtable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());I'm having incompatible types. @MadProgrammer

Comment: typecast jtable to DefaultTableModel then try. like ((DefaultTableModel)jbable).setModel(......)

Comment: @Dilini `setModel` makes no return. What I mean is, if you want a quick way to clear a `JTable` of it's contents, you can simply reset the model, this goes for `JList` and `JComboBox` as well...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Please can you explain me what to fill the (..). so sorry to giving so much trouble.is this should be.    for(int i = count-1;i>=0;i--){
        DefaultTableModel df = new  ((DefaultTableModel)jtable1).setModel(..);
        DefaultTableModel dft = (DefaultTableModel)jtable1.getModel();
        dft.removeRow(i);
                      v.add(rs1.getInt("itid"));
                v.add(rs1.getString("itname"));
                v.add(rs1.getInt("qty"));
                v.add(rs1.getDouble("sprice"));
                v.add(rs1.getDouble("total"));
                dft.addRow(v);
    }